# Function imports cannot be created for composable functions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have generated Entity CodeBlock for my database objects and choose some of my user defined scalar functions. But when i tried to double click on functions in Model.Store to import function i get this error.

Function imports cannot be created for composable functions.

How can i import my functions?

Comment: what is the return type? Perhaps this may help if you have complex return types - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nihitk/archive/2010/04/23/ado-net-entity-designer-in-vs-2010-stored-procedure-return-type-shape-sensing.aspx

Comment: varchar(100) is not a complex type i guess...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what I was seeing with the ExecuteFunction, but it wasn't working.  I finally got an end-to-end solution together with help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968592/ef4-how-to-call-a-scalar-udf) and the article shown in the other responses.

Step one is to get the function into your EDMX file:

```
    <Function Name="ProcessReplacements" ReturnType="nvarchar(max)" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="Data">
      <Parameter Name="VersionId" Type="uniqueidentifier" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="SurveyId" Type="uniqueidentifier" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="Input" Type="nvarchar(max)" Mode="In" />
    </Function>
```

Step two is to setup a class in the same namespace as the EDMX file (easily done by creating class in the same directory as the EDMX file:

```
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
namespace Same.As.Edmx
{
    public static class EdmFunctions
    {
        [EdmFunction("SurveyDesignerModel.Store", "ProcessReplacements")]
        public static string ProcessReplacements(Guid VersionId, Guid SurveyId, string Input)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

Step three is to write an object query pointing to the function:

```
    using System.Data.Objects;
    protected string ProcessReplacements(Guid versionId, Guid surveyId, string input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return null;

        List<ObjectParameter> parameters = new List<ObjectParameter>(3);
        parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("VersionId", versionId));
        parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("SurveyId", surveyId));
        parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Input", input));

        var output = db.CreateQuery<string>("SurveyDesignerModel.Store.ProcessReplacements(@VersionId, @SurveyId, @Input)", parameters.ToArray())
            .Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return output;
    }
```

The key for me was the CreateQuery call on the object context and syntax of the "query string".  Notice the fully qualified reference to the function defined in the EDMX, that was my missing link :-)

Comment: Is there a way to use such imported function in the SQL statements in CommandText property of the EntityDataSource?

Comment: Wow, actually, it is: http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET35#CallingSqlClrAggregatesLinqToEntities

Comment: This is some great info, however, I didn't need to do your step two...just step three did it for me.

Comment: What's the proper namespace usage? Can you explain the "SurveyDesignerModel.Store"? I'm always having the error:
System.Data.EntitySqlException : 'fn_GetStatus' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 1. :(

Comment: My model's namespace is "SurveyDesignerModel".  I suspect store is a standard name applied to the XML that's created.  I would expect yours to be "Namespace.Store".  In step one of the answer, when editing the EDMX file, I see this on line 7 (so near the top): <schema Namespace="SurveyDesignerModel.Store"...

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. You cannot create function import for SQL function but only for SQL Stored procedure. You can import SQL function to your storage model but you must manually create method to call the function:

```
public static class EdmFunctions
{
    [EdmFunction("TestModel.Store", "FunctionName")]
    public static string SomeName(string someParam)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This function is only for L2E query.");
    }
}
```

Namespace in `EdmFunction` must be namespace of the store container (SSDL in EDMX file) and name must be the name of imported function. This method makes no sense when called in .NET code. Because of that it throws exception. It is only for queries translated to SQL = linq-to-entities.

Comment: I have used this approach, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have done:
    public static class EdmFunctions
    {
        [EdmFunction("Model.Store", "PKG_TURNUS_SUMUKE")]
        public static int turnusSumuke(decimal ALNR, decimal ATID,   decimal AUKENR)
    {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This function is only  for L2E query.");
    }
    }
I have called this function from L2E but the query returns null.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and successfully resolved it. An original MSDN article on this subject is here: [How to: Call Custom Database Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847.aspx)