# EF4 how to call a scalar UDF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to call a scalar UDF in SQL Server from the entity framework. It shows up in the the model browser in the Store section.

Any help is Appreciated..

```
 //In the EDMX File it shows up in the storage model

<Function Name="GetPerformanceIndicator" ReturnType="float" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="inv" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="fund" Type="int" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="curr" Type="int" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
      </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>

// In the Code I am trying to call as mentioned in the Forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/92a3214b-a662-44d5-bed3-11eae9926be6/
var query = _context.CreateQuery<double>("IRISModel.Store.GetPerformanceIndicator(@curr, @fund, @inv)",
                        new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("inv", invfund.Investors.Investor_ID),
                        new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("fund", invfund.Funds.Fund_ID),
                       new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("curr", invfund.Currency.Currency_ID));

                    var x2 = query.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking);

                    x = x2.FirstOrDefault(); //<<-- This always return zero
```

Comment: What does your scalar function look like?  Does it work outside of EF?

Comment: yes it works outside EF.. it takes 3 integers and returns a float. IT works if i execute directly using tSQL in ssms.

Comment: Have you tried [this approach?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847%28VS.100%29.aspx)  Note the use of an `[EdmFunction]` attribute to provide the hook to EF for calling your custom function.

Comment: Thanks Robert.. this looks like working.. while this is not a preferred method to just make a call to get one value:) But is a good workaround. Please post it as an answer and I will accept. I cannot give credit in a comment :) Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [this approach?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847%28VS.100%29.aspx)  Note the use of an `[EdmFunction]` attribute to provide the hook to EF for calling your custom function.