# Calling database function from C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, function

Ok, so I'm not using Sql Client.

I have an .edmx file in my project and in it are the tables, the views and the stored procedures. I know how to call them from my project. But I have some functions in the Server Explorer. How to call them via code?

Comment: You want to call a stored procedure using EF? Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov No. I want to call a function.

Comment: A *function*? Never heard of such notion in a SQL database.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Can you see this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov And here: https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+entity+model+linq+function#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=database+function+vs+stored+proc&oq=database+function+vs+&aq=0&aqi=g1g-K2&aql=&gs_l=serp.3.0.0j0i30l2.132391.135741.3.136799.21.14.0.7.7.0.125.1436.7j7.14.0...0.0.Rr2NXbRQ7FU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1c83fcc631ee06da&biw=1920&bih=955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was writing a stored procedure with the same code as the stored procedure and import it in the .edmx file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add those function to EDMX in Wizard (update model from database) and after that you have to manually create static function accepting parameters with same names and marked with `EdmFunction` attribute (examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866705/function-imports-cannot-be-created-for-composable-functions)). Now you have mapped function which can be used inside Linq-to-entities queries. EF provider will correctly translate your CLR call to SQL function call in SQL query.

EF 4.0 doesn't support table valued functions (this support is added in EF 4.5 / .NET 4.5). Also this mapping works only with EDMX - not with code first.

Comment: But I can only add views, tables and stored procedures to my .edmx file.

Comment: Functions which can be imported will be under stored procedures.