# LINQ To Entities "Function imports cannot be created for composable functions"

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a scalar value function in my SQL Server that returns a ID **(int)** based on a text entry **(varchar(max))**, the function is used to return the Product SKU ID of a certain serial number).

Here is the SQL function.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fGetPSKU]
(
  @SerialNumber varchar(MAX)
)
returns int
begin

  /*
    local variables  
  */
  declare cmodel cursor local for
    select PSKU.ProductSKUID, PSKU.ProductSKUValadationStart, PSKU.ProductSKUValadationEnd, PSKU.ProductSKUValadationMask, PSKU.PruductSKUValadationLength
      from SCM.dbo.ProductSKU PSKU
      where PSKU.ProductSKUActive = 0
        and PSKU.ProductSKURequiresValadation = 1
      order by PSKU.ProductSKUValadationEnd - PSKU.ProductSKUValadationStart desc, len(PSKU.ProductSKUValadationMask) desc, PSKU.ProductSKUDateCreated desc, PSKU.ProductSKUID desc
  declare @mid int
  declare @mstart int
  declare @mend int
  declare @masks varchar(max)
  declare @lengths varchar(255)
  declare @found int
  declare @model int

  /* 
    main code 
  */
  set @found = 0
  set @model = -1

  open cmodel

  fetch next from cmodel into @mid, @mstart, @mend, @masks, @lengths

  while @@fetch_status = 0 and @found = 0
  begin

    if exists
      (
        select null
          from SCM..fParseDelimited(@masks, ',')
          where ids = substring(@SerialNumber, @mstart, @mend - @mstart + 1)
      )
      and exists
      (
        select null
          from SCM..fParseDelimited(@lengths, ',')
          where ids = convert(varchar, len(@SerialNumber))
      )
    begin
      set @found = 1
      set @model = @mid

    end

    fetch next from cmodel into @mid, @mstart, @mend, @masks, @lengths

  end

  close cmodel

  return @model

end
```

Once I have it Imported on my Entity Framework I get the following error: **Function imports cannot be created for composable functions** when I am trying to create a Function Import. I have read this similar **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866705/function-imports-cannot-be-created-for-composable-functions)**
but it's not very clear on where and what to create in your EF to get the successful execution of the function.

Any advice/help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which step weren't you able to follow in the post you reference?

Comment: @WouterdeKort I am not sure where to create the function in the edmx. In **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847%28VS.100%29.aspx)** Microsoft Link they say it needs to be in the SSDL. Not to sure where that is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Funcion import into the SSDL part of your EDMX. If you open the EDMX with an XML editor you will see that the EDMX consists of three parts:

- SSDL
- CSDL
- C-S Mapping

SSDL is inside the `edm:StorageModels` node. That's where you need to add your function import. If you open the EDMX file as XML in Visual Studio you will get IntelliSense that shows that you can add a Function node.

Comment: You Sir! Are a gentlemen and a scholar!